# Need to convert .bed to .vcf. Can the reference build (and necessary .fasta) be determined for a .bed file?

Tags: ngs, fasta, vcf, bed

I have some .bed files (and .bim and .fam files) containing data for a number of different samples, and I need to convert them to .vcf.

I've found [`bed2vcf` which is from the `bedr` R package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/bedr/versions/1.0.7/topics/bed2vcf), and also available as a stand-alone python program of the same name, but it requires a .fasta file corresponding to the reference genome used to create the .bed file. So we need to know what genome reference build was used to get the right `.fasta`.

**Question** Is there any tool or way to inspect the files I have and determine what genome reference build is required to do a correct conversion to .vcf, or is there any other method?

There is a `bed2vcf` related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63306507/convert-bed-file-to-vcf-with-bed2vcf-function).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So it seems like you've (very reasonably) got confused between the two different types of bed file - one of them is used to store [genomic coordinate data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BED_(file_format)) and then one is used as part of the plink data set. You want the latter, but I function you used is for the former. Annoying I know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different kinds of `.bed` files in bioinformatics; one related to storing [genomic coordinate data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BED_(file_format)) and one which is part of the [plink binary dataset](https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink/1.9/formats#bed), so it's important to check which kind of file you are actually converting. If you have `.bed`, `.bim` and `.fam` files, you could use [PLINK 2.0](https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink/2.0/) to export them as VCF:

```
plink2 --bfile [prefix] --export vcf --out <prefix>
```

The relevant options from the docs:

```
<...>

  --bfile  <prefix> ['vzs'] : Specify .bed + .bim[.zst] + .fam prefix

<...>

  --out <prefix>     : Specify prefix for output files.

<...>

  --export <output format(s)...> [{01 | 12}] ['bgz'] ['id-delim='<char>]
           ['id-paste='<column set descriptor>] ['include-alt']
           ['omit-nonmale-y'] ['spaces'] ['vcf-dosage='<field>] ['ref-first']
           ['bits='<#>] ['sample-v2']
    Create a new fileset with all filters applied.  The following output
    formats are supported:

...

    * 'vcf',     : VCF (default version 4.3).  If PAR1 and PAR2 are present,
      'vcf-4.2',   they are automatically merged with chrX, with proper
      'bcf',       handling of chromosome codes and male ploidy.
      'bcf-4.2'    When the 'bgz' modifier is present, the VCF file is
                   block-gzipped.  (This always happens with BCF output.)
                   The 'id-paste' modifier controls which .psam columns are
                   used to construct sample IDs (choices are maybefid, fid,
                   iid, maybesid, and sid; default is maybefid,iid,maybesid),
                   while the 'id-delim' modifier sets the character between the
                   ID pieces (default '_').

...
```

Comment: +1, but it's probably best to use plink2 for this, I think it's much quicker and can handle some different kind of variants I think.

Comment: Oh wow. I've never worked with PLINK so this is news to me. Why in the world would they call their format "bed"? That's just...

Comment: @user438383 Updated, thanks!

Comment: @terdon as an experienced bioinformatician this shouldn’t surprise you :)